# Front Row and iTunes "watched" flags out of sync

Tags: itunes

The watched flag and playback positions in Front Row are no longer in sync with iTunes. Is there any way to resynchronize them?

If it matters, I would rather iTunes' positions replace Front Row's.

These [two](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1334535) [questions](http://discussions.info.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=6324948) on Apple Support were not useful.

**The Cause**

I recently crashed, presumably while iTunes was writing the iTunes Library and upon restart, it was "imported", with the damaged copy saved elsewhere. I still have the same iTunes Library identifier because my iPod and iPad sync as usual (rather than complaining that they're synced with another library as happens when you delete and rebuild iTunes Library.xml).

Comment: Can you provide some further details including the exact version of iTunes and Mac OS you are currently running? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot help with your original question, but you may be interested to know that Front Row was quietly removed from Lion, so if you have any imminent plans to upgrade, then it may be worth bearing in mind that you could be wasting your time trying to fix this.

Comment: There does exist a hack procedure to reenable it though, see http://www.mac-hatter.com/blog/frontrowenablerforlion

Comment: I would say you should expect these sorts of bugs if you decide to hack though.